# Indexing a separate pandas dataframe from a value in current dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dissimilarly shaped dataframes. I need to calculate a new column in one from values in it and another dataframe which does not have the same number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd

data_m = [['Aluminum', 120], ['Steel', 250], ['Titanium', 202]]
df_metal = pd.DataFrame(data_m, columns=['Material', 'E'])

data_c = [['Aluminum', 0.050], ['Aluminum', 0.063], ['Steel', 0.010], ['Titanium', 0.028], ['Aluminum', 0.050]]
df_comp = pd.DataFrame(data_c, columns=['Layer', 'Thickness'])
```

I need another column in `df_comp` named `E/t` such that the column is a calculation of the appropriate value from `df_metal` based on the value in `df_comp['Layer']`.
I have tried several failed iterations, and the closest I have found is:

```
df_comp['E/t'] = df_metal.loc[df_comp['Layer'] == df_comp['Layer'], 'E'] / df_comp['Thickness']
```

However, that only works for the number of rows available in `df_metal` and results in:

```
      Layer  Thickness           E/t
0  Aluminum      0.050   2400.000000
1  Aluminum      0.063   3968.253968
2     Steel      0.010  20200.000000
3  Titanium      0.028           NaN
4  Aluminum      0.050           NaN
```

I need to result in:

```
      Layer  Thickness           E/t
0  Aluminum      0.050   2400.000000
1  Aluminum      0.063   1904.761905
2     Steel      0.010  25000.000000
3  Titanium      0.028   7214.285714
4  Aluminum      0.050   2400.000000
```

I truly think there is a simple solution for this, but my experience in pandas is limited.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `Material` as index in `df_metal` and divide:

```
df_comp['E/t'] = df_comp['Thickness'].rdiv(df_metal.set_index('Material')['E']
                                           .reindex(df_comp['Layer']).values 
                                          )
```

Output:

```
      Layer  Thickness           E/t
0  Aluminum      0.050   2400.000000
1  Aluminum      0.063   1904.761905
2     Steel      0.010  25000.000000
3  Titanium      0.028   7214.285714
4  Aluminum      0.050   2400.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the dataframes and then compute the column:

```py
x = df_comp.merge(df_metal, left_on="Layer", right_on="Material", how="left")

df_comp["E/t"] = x["E"] / x["Thickness"]
print(df_comp)
```

Prints:

```
      Layer  Thickness  Material    E           E/t
0  Aluminum      0.050  Aluminum  120   2400.000000
1  Aluminum      0.063  Aluminum  120   1904.761905
2     Steel      0.010     Steel  250  25000.000000
3  Titanium      0.028  Titanium  202   7214.285714
4  Aluminum      0.050  Aluminum  120   2400.000000
```